# Nuisance parameters and $o_p(n^{-1/4})$ convergence: citation

Tags: mathematical-statistics, asymptotics

I'm looking for an original reference to a proof idea.

Suppose we have $n$ iid observations $(X_i,Y_i)$ and an estimating function
$$\bar U(\beta;\alpha)=\frac{1}{n}U(\beta;\alpha; X_i,Y_i)$$
where we are interested in estimating $\beta\in \mathbb{R}^p$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^q$ is a nuisance parameter.

Further suppose that
$$E[\bar U(\beta_0,\alpha)]=0$$
for every fixed $\alpha$ (or every fixed $\alpha$ in some suitable open set or whatever).  This happens in GEE when $\alpha$ are working correlation parameters and in survey statistics when $\alpha$ are raking parameters and a variety of other settings.

Under classical smoothness assumptions, and using the fact that $$\frac{\partial }{\partial\alpha}E[\bar U(\beta_0,\alpha)]=0,$$
it can be shown that if $\|\hat\alpha-\alpha^*\|=o_p(n^{-1/4})$, there is a consistent and asymptotically Normal sequence of plug-in estimators of $\beta_0$ solving $$\bar U(\beta; \hat\alpha)=0$$ with the limiting variance depending on $\hat\alpha$ only through $\alpha^*$.

**Question:** This argument was certainly known in the mid-1990s, and I was told it was first developed by Whitney Newey, but I don't know where. Does anyone know the Newey reference? Also, does anyone know an early reference by someone else?

Comment: Hi, did you get to the bottom of this?

Comment: No, I'm still no further forward.

Answer (score 2):

The paper I'm looking for [appears to be](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2951752)

Newey, W. K. (1994). The Asymptotic Variance of Semiparametric Estimators. Econometrica, 62(6), 1349–1382. https://doi.org/10.2307/2951752

The fourth-root convergence assumption appears in the discussion following Assumption 5.1